# How to stop the file watcher prompts when editing scss files?

Tags: sass, phpstorm

I use another compiler for my SCSS files so I don't need PhpStorm to handle this. But every time I open the editor up and load up a .scss file I get the message `"File watcher 'SCSS' is available for this file. Description: 'Compiles .scss files into .css files'"`. If I click "Dismiss" then the message does not show up for this file again until restarting the editor.

Is there a way to disable these messages as clicking 'dismiss' 10 times a day is getting a little annoying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well .. clicking on "Dismiss" SHOULD stop showing this message.

Since it does not: you can disable that message completely:

`Settings (Preferences on Mac) | Inspections | File Watchers | File watcher available`